# Safari/Webkit Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP) breaks application running in an iframe

Tags: iframe, safari, webkit

I have an app on foo.com which has an iframe that loads another application from bar.com. The bar.com webapp relies on maintaining session with a session cookie which it issues on the response to the first request to bar.com. ITP at some point decides it's no longer going to send the bar.com session cookie on requests to bar.com in that iframe... and the bar.com webapp goes fubar.

The arrangement works fine if I disable "prevent cross-site tracking" in Safari. And it works fine in any other browser.

I think ITP is deciding that the cookie being loaded in the iframe is a third-party context. And although the user directly interacts with the webapp presented in the iframe (clicks, drags, etc), ITP does not register that as first-party interaction.

That's all mighty unfortunate and I'm not finding a way to work around it. Any suggestions? There are no ads or ad-tracking involved here.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel there is a bug in the way ITP is handling your web app, you should file a Radar so we can investigate.

As it stands, unless your app is embedded on a number of other sites, it’s unlikely it would have been flagged as a tracker.

Can you give details about your application, and where it might be used so we can investigate?